# Update data in iOS TableView cells from webserver (ASIHTTPRequest, PHP, mysql)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, tableview, asihttprequest

I have tableview where is name and status. Status is changed when come apple push notification (APNS). 
But I have this problem. What can I do, if notification didn't come? Or if user tap on close button of this message. 
I try to update table by using ASIHTTPRequest:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
    HomePageTableCell *cell = (HomePageTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [device valueForKey:@"name"];

    if ([[device valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToNumber:@1]) 
    {
        cell.status.text = @"Not configured";
        cell.stav.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"not_configured.png"];
    }
    if ([[device valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToNumber:@2]) 
    {
        //some other states
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I try this to change status before cell is loading...

```
- (void) getStatus:(NSString *)serialNumber
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"link to my server"];

    __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request_b = request;
    request.delegate = self;

    [request setPostValue:@"updatedevice" forKey:@"cmd"];
    [request setPostValue:serialNumber forKey:@"serial_number"]; //get status of this serial number

    [request setCompletionBlock:^
     {
         if([self isViewLoaded])
         {
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
             if([request_b responseStatusCode] != 200)
             {
                 ShowErrorAlert(@"Comunication error", @"There was an error communicating with the server");                     
             }
             else
             {                                      
                 NSString *responseString = [request_b responseString];
                 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
                 NSDictionary *result = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

                 status = [result objectForKey:@"status"];
                 NSInteger statusInt = [status intValue]; //change to int value

                 //here I want to change cell status in SQLite, but don't know how
                 //something with indexPath.row? valueForKey:@"status"???                
             }
         }
     }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^
     {
         if ([self isViewLoaded])
         {
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
             ShowErrorAlert(@"Error", [[request_b error] localizedDescription]);

         }
     }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Or it is better way to change status in my table view if apple notification didn't come or user didn't tap on notification message? Thanks

EDIT:
I don't know how to store data to NSManagedObject *device. Can you help me with this?
I try this, but it didn't works: (on place where you write)

```
NSInteger statusInt = [status intValue]; //change to int value
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[device setValue:statusInt forKey:@"status"];
```

EDIT2:
I get it, but problem is with reload table data

```
 NSString *responseString = [request_b responseString];
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
 NSDictionary *result = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

 NSString *status = [result objectForKey:@"status"];
 NSInteger statusInt = [status intValue]; //change to int value
 NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [device setValue:statusInt forKey:@"status"]; //there is problem in save statusInt
```

//     [device setValue:@5 forKey:@"status"]; //if I do this it is ok status is integer16 type

and second problem is in that reload table data. I put there this

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

but It reloading again and again in loop, what is wrong? I thing there is infinite loop, if I didn't reload table data changes will be visible in next app load. I think problem is that I call

```
- (void) getStatus:(NSString *)serialNumber atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Better should be in viewDidLoad or viewDidApper, but I don't know how make loop for all devices and call

```
    [self getStatus:[device valueForKey:@"serialNumber"] atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

on that place.

EDIT3:

what if I do it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self updateData];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)updateData 
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
    //request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"serialNumber"];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext
                               executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    NSArray *result = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"serialNumber"]; 

    //there I get all serialNumbers of my devices and than I call method getStatus and get "new" status and than update it in Core Data. 
}
```

Is that good way to solve this problem? I think better will be if I call getStatus method only one times and get array of statuses.

Maybe I can set all serialNubers in one variable ('xxx','yyyy','zzz') and on server do SELECT * FROM Devices WHERE serialNumber in (serialNuber).

Do you think this could work? I don't have experience how to take data from array to string like ('array_part1','array_part2'....)

Comment: Please tag your question properly; for example knowing the platform (OSX or iOS) is more important than knowing the IDE you use to develop your program.

Comment: Ok, sorry no problem. I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where in your code do you call `[UITableView reloadData]`?

You should call `reloadData` on your tableview once you have retrieved the new data from the server. As your server call is async the server call will run on a separate thread while the main thread continues, therefore I presume you have the following problem...

```
- (void) ...
{
    [self getStatus:@"SERIAL_NUMBER"];
    [self reloadData]; // This will be called before the async server call above has finished
}
```

Therefore you are reloading the original data and therefore the new data, which may have loaded a few seconds after, wont be shown.

To fix this, adjust the `[getStatus:]` method to call the `[UITableView reloadData]` method on server response.

```
[request setCompletionBlock:^
 {
     if([self isViewLoaded])
     {
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         if([request_b responseStatusCode] != 200)
         {
             ShowErrorAlert(@"Comunication error", @"There was an error communicating with the server");

         }
         else
         {                 

             NSString *responseString = [request_b responseString];
             SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
             NSDictionary *result = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

             status = [result objectForKey:@"status"];
             NSInteger statusInt = [status intValue]; //change to int value

             // Store the server response in NSManagedObject *device,
             // which will be used as the data source in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

             // Once stored, check the tableview isn't NULL and therefore can be accessed
             // As this call is async the tableview may have been removed and therefore
             // a call to it will crash
             if(tableView != NULL)
             {
                    [tableView reloadData];
             }           
         }
     }
 }];
```

ASIHTTPRequest is also no longer supported by the developers, I suggest you look into [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

---

**Update**

In response to the problem you are now having with setting the `statusInt` within the device `NSManagedObject`

```
 NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [device setValue:statusInt forKey:@"status"]; //there is problem in save statusInt
```

This is caused as `statusInt` is an `NSInteger` which is a primary datatype and not an `NSObject` as expected by `[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:]`. From the documentation for [[NSManagedObject setValue:forKey:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html), the methods expected parameters are as follows.

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

Therefore you need to pass, in this case, an `NSNumber`. The problem with `NSInteger` is that it's simply a `dynamic typedef` for the largest `int` datatype based on the current system. From `NSInteger`'s implementation you can see the abstraction.

```
#if __LP64__
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

If your current system is 64-bit it will use the larger `long` datatype.

Now, technically the returned `status` value from the server can be stored as it is without any conversion as an `NSString`. When you need to retrieve and use the primary datatype of `int` you can use the `[NSString intValue]` method you have already used.

Although it's best practice to use a `NSNumberFormatter` which can be useful for `locale` based number adjustments and ensuring no invalid characters are present.

```
NSString *status = [result objectForKey:@"status"];
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber * statusNumber = [f numberFromString:status];
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[device setValue:statusNumber forKey:@"status"];
```

To retrieve the primary datatype when you wish to use the `int` within your code, simply call the `[NSNumber intValue]`.

```
NSNumber *statusNumber = [device objectForKey:@"status"];
int statusInt = [statusNumber intValue];
```

---

As for the problem you are having with the infinite loop, this is caused by called `[... getStatus:atIndexPath:]`, which contains the method call `reloadData`, from within `[UITableView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`.

This is because `reloadData` actually calls `[UITableView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`.
Therefore your code continuously goes as the following...

```
Initial UITableView data load -> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: -> getStatus:atIndexPath: -> Server Response -> reloadData -> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: -> getStatus:atIndexPath: -> Server Response -> reloadData -> ...
```

Unfortunately you cant just force one cell to update, you have to request the `UITableView` to reload all data using `reloadData`. Therefore, if possible, you need to adjust your server to return an unique ID for devices so you can adjust only the updated device within your `NSManagedObject`.

A suggested alteration for the `getStatus` method could be just to use the `serialNumber` if this is stored within the `NSManagedObject` as a key.

```
- (void) getStatus:(NSString*)serialNumber
```

Comment: I edit my Question with another problem. And thanks for that AFNetworking, I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: Where in your code do you use CoreData to set the devices? I see you have an `NSArray` called `devices` which holds `NSManagedObject`'s. The reason why `[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` doesn't work in the server response of `[self getStatus:]` method is that `indexPath.row` is from the `[UITableViewDelegate tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` and therefore `indexPath.row` is `NULL` within the server response code. Read up on [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and [NSManagedObject](http://bit.ly/17oYVs8)

Comment: I update my question, now I know how to save, but there is new problems.

Comment: sorry I have been out of office. Hmm problem is that I need to update and reload all table cells. Is there a possibility to make some function which return me all table cells just like in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:? or it will be better to call some function which return me all devices from NSManagedObject and than update them?

Comment: The `UITableView` class method `reloadData` will reload all cells regardless of wether the data has updated or not. Your `NSManagedObject` is essentially your `dataSource` for the `UITableView`. So yes, as suggested in my answer you should have a method which either fills an `NSManagedObject` or updates an entry (if the object is already loaded into memory) then calls `[UITableView reloadData]` which will update the cells accordingly by looping through `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: "Unfortunately you cant just force one cell to update, you have to request the UITableView to reload all data using reloadData." - This is plain an simple WRONG! What about: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: ?? Just specify one row in your indexpath and voilá, just that one cell gets its data reloaded. There's no need to reload ALL cells.